# DrRacket plot "could not determine sensible plot bounds"

Tags: plot, scheme, lisp, racket

I am trying to plot this function:

```
#lang racket

(define (smoothsquare x)
  ((smooth square) x))

(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(require plot)
(plot (function smoothsquare (- 1) 1))

(define dx 0.00001)

(define (smooth f)
  (lambda (x) (/ (+ (f (- x dx))
                    (f x)
                    (f (+ x dx)))
                 3)))
```

but I get the following error:
". plot: could not determine sensible plot bounds; got x ∈ [-1,1], y ∈ [#f,#f]"

Why is that? Is there a way around this? I can think of a sensible plot bound for the y-axis, namely [-1,1], but I'm not sure how to tell it that.

I have read the intro here https://docs.racket-lang.org/plot/intro.html but it isn't helping me

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you define `smooth` too late. That is, when you call `plot`, the plot library attempts to call your `smoothsquare`, which in turn tries to call `smooth`, but `smooth` is not defined yet because it's only defined after the `plot` call is finished.

Following code should work:

```
#lang racket

(require plot)

(define dx 0.00001)

(define (smooth f)
  (lambda (x)
    (/ (+ (f (- x dx))
          (f x)
          (f (+ x dx)))
       3)))

(define (smoothsquare x)
  ((smooth square) x))

(define (square x)
  (* x x))

(plot (function smoothsquare -1 1))
```